# After Monte Carlo simulations, should I do multiple test correction?

Tags: monte-carlo

I performed Monte Carol simulation to assess the significance of a certain motif in genome DNA. I also carried out hundred different motifs using the same procedure. So I got a bunch of p-values for those motifs. Now the question is, should I do multiple test correction for those p-values?

Comment: In Monte-Carlo, aren't you supposed to average those paths and arrive at the expectation? You should only have a single P-value for the expectation. I don't understand why you would do perform multiple-test corrections between the scenarios.

Comment: Suppose that I have motif A which has a p-value after Monte Carol 0.001.Motif B 0.004, Motif C 0.005, Motif D 0.004, Motif E 0.4....and Motif unknown 0.4. Each motif has a p-value from simulation. I wonder if any adjustment is needed.

Comment: p-value is a probability for a certain scenario. Those scenarios are independent, so you shouldn't need to adjust them. MC gives you __distribution__ of the p-values (and other statistics). You'll need to average out the scenarios to arrive at a scenario that is most likely to happen statistically. This scenario will be the your expectation and you'll have a single p-value from it.

Comment: The Monte Carlo part is unclear. Is it used to compute a p-value? If so, how is it used?

Comment: My MC procedure is the following: first, I count the occurrence (n) of a certain motif appearing in authentic alignment file. second, I generated 40000 pseudo-alignments, then I got a distribution of the motif occurrence. Third, I calculated the P-value. If the occurrence in 40000 equal or larger than that generated from the authentic, then a counter accrues, say in this case, m, which is the frequency of events equal or larger than n. P-value is calculated using this formula: m/40000. I have about 900 motifs, I computed 900 motif p-value using those three steps. Do I need to adjust them?